# How to Pass Data from from Parent to Child in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, parent-child

When I try to pass data from parent to child component. I'm getting an undefined message in the console.
Here my message is just a string.

1. child.component.ts  - >[ upload-doc.component.ts ]

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-doc',
  template: `
      Say {{ message}}
  `,
  templateUrl: './upload-doc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-doc.component.css']
})
export class UploadDocComponent implements OnInit {

   

   @Input() message: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Child Component " + this.message); // printing on console
    
  }

}
```

2. parent.component.ts - > [ register-page.component.ts ]

```
@Component({
  
  selector: 'app-register-page',
  
  templateUrl: './register-page.component.html',
   template: `<app-upload-doc [message]="message"> </app-upload-doc>`,
  styleUrls: ['./register-page.component.css']
})

export class RegisterPageComponent implements OnInit {

  
 constructor() { }
  message = "message from parent"

 ngOnInit(){ }

}
```

It's giving me the output as **Child Component undefined**. How to get rid of this undefined thing.

Comment: Please show us your  register-page.component.html file.   That is where  you make the connection with an  attribute in the  tag for  UploadDocComponent.

Comment: Why do you have both a `template` *and* a `templateUrl` declared in your components?

Answer (score 0):

(parent) app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  message: string = "Hey there!";

  constructor() { }
}
```

(parent) app.component.html

```
<app-child [message]="message"></app-child>
```

---

child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() message:string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.message)
  }
}
```

child.component.html

```
<p>
    {{ message }}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be using the `@ViewChild` to communicate between parent and child components or between any components.

Steps:

1. Create a handler to access the child component in the parent component.

```
// Parent.component.ts

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('attendance') _attendance: AttendanceCardComponent

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this._attendance.passSomeMessage(this.someData); // this is a function inside the **child component (here, AttendanceCardComponent)
  }
}
```

2. Add the marker for detecting the child component in the Parent.component.html

*Note: The marker has to have the same name given in the* `@ViewChild()` *selector.```

```
<section>
      <h6><b>My Activity</b></h6>
      <app-attendance-card #attendance></app-attendance-card>
</section>
```

**That's it!**. You're all good to go.

Comment: For simply passing values from parent to child this is **not** what you should do. Using `@Input` (property binding) is the correct way.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm just giving a more genric solution for this. What would happen if we've to pass multiple data to the child?
Won't ```@input``` method be tedious? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Sure, the html will bloat a bit (you bloat the ts), but `@Input` is not a one time use. If the value changes in parent, it will be updated in child too. With `@ViewChild` you'd have to do that manually. Another part is that `[]` and `()` is common notation and another person will know what happens right away just by looking at the template. And of course, if you have two way binding (output in child), you'd have to actively bind the parent to the child.

Comment: Okay. So it depends on your use case.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit this line
@Input() message: string; --> @Input('message') message: string;

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are using the wrong [lifecycle hook](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-lifecycle-hooks). At the point of the `ngOnInit()` you do not yet have the input value. Instead, you should use `ngAfterContentInit` to see the content after it receives the input.

So the only change you need is

```
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log("Child Component " + this.message); // printing on console    
  }
```